# New Reputation Calculation - was the community asked?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Stack Exchange is [recalculating everyone's reputation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) to award more reputation for receiving an upvote on a question. To my knowledge, the community wasn't asked for input on whether this was a good idea or not. Considering that 2.4 million people are about to receive varying levels of reputation increase and that's kind of a big deal - was the community consulted somewhere and I just missed it? And if they weren't consulted...why not? Seems like an awfully big move to make unilaterally.

Comment: Depends on how you define "community"

Comment: @KevinB I'd settle for "anyone outside the company that participates in Stack Exchange Q&A" at the moment.

Comment: I'm told it was shared with mods

Comment: @mason then the answer is yes, due to the fact that it was leaked prior.

Comment: @rene Shared as in "Hey we're going to roll this thing out in about 10 minutes" or shared as in "Hey, we're considering this change. We want to gather your feedback about it before we implement it"?

Comment: [6 to 8 days ago](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/1410/2019/11/5)

Comment: I didn't see any twitter posts asking, so I'm gonna say no. If you meant Meta, then they stopped asking long ago too.

Comment: As somebody who has never cared about reputation (and trashed a high rep account on a small site that I earned in the early days when 'candy was being given put for asking or answering anything', "quite frankly my dear, I don't give a damn."

Comment: Not _asked_ perhaps, but there was [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337843/should-the-weight-of-question-upvotes-be-increased-network-wide) discussion

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl I don't care so much about the reputation either...except that it affects what actions you can take on the site. And that can have effects on the quality that should be discussed with the community before being rolled out.

Comment: I guess we are no longer optimizing for pearls.

Comment: @Skooba we're just optimizing

Comment: @Skooba It looks like the site is rather _optimizing for advertisement inverstors_ and _"welcoming"_ at any price.

Comment: Farewell good SNR

Comment: We weren't asked about it, but it was leaked early enough for everyone to think about it and ask a question on meta if they wanted to oppose it.

Comment: @Skooba It is important to note that according to SE's data, changing the vote for questions did not result in a greater emphasis on quality questions and answers. It was a failed change.

Comment: At least on SO this will make sock puppeting and rep farming even more attractive. With how low of quality most questions are (and still get answered) a moderately one will reap 10-40reps.

Comment: That whole blog post somehow creates the impression as if answering questions would be the easy part compared to _can I haz code plz_. That sounds wrong.

Comment: I think you'd better get used to the idea that community participants no longer have any ownership or say in their communities (if, in fact, they ever did).

You don't have to take my word for it.  All you have to do is spend a few minutes looking around on this meta site to see that.

Comment: @mason, genuine question to which I don't have an answer: how likely is it that this will elevate somebody into the exalted regions undeservedly? (I suspect SE have access to this data, and I hope it informed their decision).

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl: If the recalculation has taken place, it's already happened multiple times.  "Undeservedly" is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Quite.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl Well considering 2.4 million people are getting rep bumps....I'd say it's quite likely that a lot going to receive privileges that up until now haven't believed they've earned. As far as actual numbers, I don't have the time to calculate that now.

Comment: I would only support this recalc if those with new privileges are going to use them wisely and then I don't mean leaving comments *Help me I have the same problem* but flagging, downvoting, reviewing.

Comment: They don't have to ask our permission for every decision they make. This reputation change seems reasonable (to a pretty arbitrary dynamic, anyway). Do we really need to go up in arms every time a company makes a decision without our approval?

Comment: @Lyd - I see your point. It can be very tiring given it is indeed **every time** and every decision.

Comment: @Lyd When the company is built on the contributions of the user, then yes.

Comment: @Lyd: No, but let's not pretend that, just because this decision might be innocuous, that it somehow relieves corporate from engaging in meaningful ways with their communities.

Comment: @Skooba But as the platform providers, autonomy is beneficial to both parts, no? We are not up in arms because they didn't consult us this time. We are up in arms every time they make an independent decision. When they do ask for our input, we downvote them into the thousands. We are the content creators, but expecting the ropes of the company in exchange feels unreasonable.

Comment: @Lyd I don't think they would be downvoted so heavily if they actually sought community input before taking action, and actually listened to the community's input rather than just pretending they know best.

Comment: @mason But that's the thing, there's no way to win this. Every decision is being condensed into the outrage and drama bucket. Of course the community input is important, but I don't think we have made a good job at proving that we can make a positive difference, or be constructive. No matter what they do we spit flames. How is that useful?

Comment: @Lyd I would say most of the time, the issues the users react heavily to (positive or negative) are the ones that directly affect the content they have created. Also, without the content, there is no company, so it is not out of line to want to have input on that process. No one (at least that I know of) is saying users need to have control over daily operations, hiring decisions, or other things that the company does.

Comment: @Lyd If I was an investor, I'd be paying careful attention to what the people responsible for making my investment valuable think. They're either going to start listening, or their investment is going to lose all its value and turn into Quora or Yahoo Answers and everyone will go elsewhere to get their help.

Comment: @Skooba It goes both ways, without the platform there's nothing at all.

Comment: @mason Pay attention to what? The community is screaming in all directions, there's too much noise.

Comment: @Lyd It's not just noise. It's valuable information. People being upset at every decision that's made is good to know. They just haven't course corrected yet. They will, or this whole thing will fall apart.

Comment: @mason And when and if it's remade, the same dynamics will apply, unless it's non-profit non-centralized or something.

Comment: @Lyd It can be run by a benevolent dictator or the other options you mentioned. There's not an easy process of getting there with the current SE software since the company owns it. But if we're talking about brand new software, then sure a new entity running the show is viable.

Comment: @Lyd but the platform was built on a understanding of a community approach, where the "company" wasn't above users, it was collective process. Surely you've been around long enough to realize that, and to realize the the community aspect has been slowly fading and replaced by a 'proft above all else' mentality.

Comment: Who cares? Numbers need to shine! https://twitter.com/spolsky/status/1191445164591665153

Comment: Well, it seems that my post [The ship is sinking, but communication is down (need orders from the captain (CEO))](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334459/the-ship-is-sinking-but-communication-is-down-need-orders-from-the-captain-ce) still applies.
Sara Chipps is probably not the person to make up directives like this.

Comment: @rene it was indeed shared with mods early, though the only thing our feedback changed was how it was presented to the community.

Comment: It's interesting that they didn't mention anything about doing this to benefit women, since women ask more questions than men, as was the reason given in the leak. Did the mod feedback cause the removal of that reason?

Comment: @Kevin yeah, I don't consider *shared* to mean that it solicited for feedback. If some of the feedback had an effect then I would call that a win.

Comment: @House-'ReinstateMonica'-man Yes, that feedback weighed heavily in that decision. It was a good point.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Did the company really change their mind about the reason for this change (being to benefit women), or does the company just not want to say that reason out loud?

Comment: @House Yes, definitely. The genesis for this change goes WAY back to discussions about restoring parity between questions and answers. I didn't hear about this study until much later, so yes, it was best not to jeopardize the launch by trying to anticipate that benefit -- See https://stackoverflow.com/c/moderators/questions/1912/1914#comment4984_1914

Comment: (to be clear, we did get responses and explanations, just no further changes)

Comment: @RobertCartaino I am not a moderator, and can't access moderator only resources. I'm less interested in the change itself, and more about *why* the company is making big unilateral changes without consulting the community. That's what I'd like for you to address here.

Comment: @mason I wasn't heavily involved in that project, but this was FAR from a unilateral decision executed haphazardly. What I *could* see was weeks (maybe months?) of discussion and outreach with satisfaction surveys, focus groups, and an extensive discussion with the Moderator representatives of your communities about if/how to roll this out. Maybe it was felt we couldn't crowdsource this decision and discuss improvements with thousands or millions of users every time; I don't know. Meta SE hasn't exactly been a constructive place to bring anything lately (which is understandable, but still...)

Comment: @RobertCartaino Man, it's just so incredibly sad to see you continually run into the same walls over and over again. Please *listen* and learn your lesson. The community *must* be consulted before any big change in the core site. It shouldn't be negotiable on whether you ask the community or not: just do it! If you want to make your case there, and request feedback, then that's great. You might get the community on board with the decisions, and you might actually find out how to accomplish the goal better with the community's input. Instead youre just creating another PR disaster. Make it stop

Comment: @RobertCartaino It might not feel constructive because you keep doing the wrong things, over and over again. If you want to feel more welcome here, then start taking the feedback to heart instead of blundering into the same mistakes all over again like some tragic version of Groundhog Day. If the feedback is overwhelmingly negative, then *don't* just say "we're going to do it anyway". That's guaranteed to piss everyone off. I shouldn't have to point this out to you. You're paid to make the right decisions here.

Comment: @mason I get it, and I agree it's a fantastic philosophy I thrive on. But man, it's become a chicken-and-egg problem here; I could come here with a cure for cancer and I would get down-votes asking why I didn't free Monica. I get it, but the system and expanding feature set is also getting too big and complex to try and outsource *every* decision a company has to make to keep moving forward. Even trying to do so *internally* was crippling us inexorably. I totally get (and love) the *default public* philosophy, but you cannot live up to that for *everything.* And it's not really my call.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I didn't say this must be done for everything. I said for big things. I don't care if you adjust the CSS on some button. Sara put together a blog post, it sounds like there may have been some more research done. How hard would it have been to put all that together as a meta post and gather and incorporate feedback? Not all that hard. And if it's not your call, then whoever's call it is needs to get in here and start answering for their actions.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Is launching things right actually important to you? Do you understand how all these initiatives you're launching are going to continue completely failing every single time until you learn to start consulting with the community again? It's going to be never ending. Saying "it's too hard" or that there's not enough time aren't really options here: you're going to kill the company and you're not going to get paychecks anymore. You can't afford *not* to listen.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Saying "Hey, what do you think of this thing we're thinking of doing?" is not some herculean task. All we're asking is to feel _included_. If it's not your call, then pass that information along

Comment: @mason I hear you. I really do. But also note how dropping by here to answer a quick question has now escalated to an existential crisis. That's what I'm referring to above. I get it, but on that note, I have to move on now.  It's not falling on deaf ears; I just have to move on to other things. Take care! Out.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Well if you had said the right things: "Yeah, we dropped the ball on this. We will roll this back, solicit feedback, and then consider relaunching again when we feel we have community backing" then this conversation would have gone very differently. That's what I'm talking about. You keep saying you heard me, but you clearly don't. You're still running banging your head against the wall like I described.

Comment: @RobertCartaino `I could come here with a cure for cancer and I would get down-votes asking why I didn't free Monica`. That's a fascinating belief. Good things the community supports still tend to get, well, community support here. See the work the devs are doing. Things the community doesn't support don't get community support. But SE acting against the interest and wishes of the community enough times seems to have convinced you that we'd downvote you to oblivion for doing the equivalent of curing cancer. That belief is the result of a cognitive bias. There is no evidence for it.

Comment: @mason "Yeah, we dropped the ball on this. We will roll this back, solicit feedback, and then consider relaunching again when we feel we have community backing"  Uh.  I doubt it.  All that would do is feed the *other* side of that argument; stop talking, start showing.  We've gotten a whole *lot* of platitudes about how SE will do better.  I rather doubt that more would mollify most people.

Comment: @fbueckert Rolling back the change would be a tangible step in the right direction, and it'd be more than just words. I think most people would see that.

Comment: [Nostalgia time](https://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2012/10/an-interview-with-jeff-atwood.php): *"This is a community-based project, and all the content comes from the people participating in the site ... the better you can serve the people doing all the work in the system, the better the system is. You need people who are willing to help, to curate. You need those people to scale. Listening to those people helps you form your community. And even though 90% of the feedback you get is crap, the other 10% is gold. You just have to listen and you’ll get it."* --Jeff Atwood

Comment: @RobertCartaino Thanks for engaging here. We understand how it might feel like an "existential crisis" to get questions where you feel swamped and expected to defend some other colleague's decision that you don't fully understand - but please understand they only @ you because so few staff engage here. Please take a step back, look again at the comments again and you'll see it's just half a dozen reasonable, constructive questions. And please also take 5 minutes to click around and see that positive posts by staff here *have* been received positively.

Comment: [There is evidence that the original decrease in reputation for upvotes to questions did not increase question quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391248/545127).

Comment: Come on @RobertC ! Do a list of post by employees in the last year and separate them by whenever the votes was overwhelmingly positive or negative. Now, look at the characteristics of the posts and try to find out what in common has both groups. Maybe trow text mining at it if it's too much.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Going to add my $0.02 here. This also got compounded (at least for me) by the fact that this got leaked, and then SE did *everything* they could to try to un-leak it. It's down to a perception problem: on one side, it getting a meaningful discussion that leads to adjustments on something from SE is like getting blood out of a stone, but they'll spend an inordinate amount of energy trying to erase something from view. Combine all those, and... well, let's just say it doesn't cast a glowing light.

Comment: In the end, it's about the method of delivery, and less about the actual content. The same, people would most likely not have been pissed off at the CoC, the license relicensing, or the firing of a mod if it was done clearly and in the open. These below-the-table deals only really help to strengthen the view that the community isn't actually part of the community, and more part of the product, which is pretty fun to think about.

Comment: Related: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13503/a-few-thousand-rep-points-more-in-one-single-day-are-a-nice-thing-but-why

Comment: Why does everything need to go to a community vote these days?

Comment: @MattK Who said everything? No one but you. Believe it or not, the community members actually have a far better idea of how Stack Exchange works than the actual staff members. If they don't see our input, the site *will* collapse. So on important issues, they need to ask the community. It doesn't necessarily have to be a vote, but gathering feedback to shape things *before* they go live is important. And by gathering feedback, I mean actually incorporating it instead of just completely ignoring it.

Comment: @mason Agree to disagree.

Comment: @MattK so you're happy with the way things have been run around here? Cool with them slandering us in public and changing licenses illegally and promoting unrelated social causes?

Comment: @mason Not sure what that has to do with your question, let's stay on topic.

Comment: @MattK You asked why does everything need to be put to a vote. I pointed out that not everything does, but that the community should have a large say in how the site is run. The reasoning for that is that SE has made terrible decision after terrible decision lately, they clearly don't know how to effectively run this site. You seem to be under the impression that they're doing fine, so there's no reason to gather community input. I'm trying to confirm whether that is truly your stance. You led us down this path, so please answer me.

Comment: @mason This is your path, not mine. I mention nothing of slander, licenses, or social causes. I appreciate your passion for the community but I'll end off again by saying let's agree to disagree.

Comment: @Lyd, re: [when they ask for our input we downvote them into the thousands](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338113/new-reputation-calculation-was-the-community-asked#comment1125440_338113)—it might hurt the poster (in an emotional sense, though probably any SO bigwig can spare the reputation), but surely that *is* input?  "I can't ask your opinion on this because you won't like it" doesn't seem like much of a justification.

Comment: @MattK I didn't say you mentioned them. But by saying that Stack Exchange does not need community input on how things should work, you must be satisfied that SE has handled those issues acceptably, or you don't know about those issues. Stop saying "agree to disagree". If you want to engage in a conversation, then take that conversation to its conclusion.

Comment: @mason Your conclusion seems to be that I must agree with you.

Comment: @MattK Of course. That's how conclusions work. I think I'm right, therefore I think others should think I'm right. If you don't think I'm right, then feel free to say something substantive to make your case, rather than dodging questions.

Comment: As a relatively new SE user with little understanding of the 'arcane wisdom of the ancients' of the old timers that have been with SE since the beginning, I am having a hard time understanding why there is such a big fuss about this whole thing. Yeah, SE should ask us about stuff. But why is making question upvotes worth more such a bad thing? The way a lot of you are bashing on this it makes me really think twice about asking questions here instead of somewhere else. If questions aren't important enough to you to be worth as many points as an answer, then how do new users get started?

Comment: To add to my last comment/question, this just adds to my growing feeling of 'SE is for the old hats to use and new guys can just go plant potatoes as far as the old guys care, because they don't know how to ask good questions'. And that is really off putting. I am sick and tired of being told 'I can't do that without more reputation' when it is a struggle to get more reputation since *all my questions have been asked already*, any question I *do* ask is looked down upon as being less worthy than an answer, and I can't answer any questions since I am *A NEW GUY that is here to LEARN*. </rant>

Comment: @RTHarston You seem to completely misunderstand the purpose of these sites. It's not a support desk. It's [not a site for tool recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), so questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58870457) aren't allowed. The point is to become a high quality repository of questions and answers within a narrow focus. So whether you're a new user or an experienced user, the expectation is the same. Research, don't post something that's been posted before.

Comment: @RTHarston They should be worth less because questions bring less value to the table, and we get a flood of low quality questions anyways. It's pretty simple to ask a good question, at least on Stack Overflow where you seem to primarily participate. No one is looking down on your questions, so long as you put forth the right amount of effort, and you're on-topic.

Comment: @mason Then what is this blasted site actually for then if I can't ask my questions? Oh, and one of the bullet points in the post that *you linked to* says: "software tools commonly used by programmers". I'm pretty sure my question was about a software tool commonly used by programmers. I wanted to know if there was something out there to sole a common problem I have run in to. How is that off topic?

Comment: @mason If people are so concerned about getting bad questions, *then why aren't the good ones valued more?* It just doesn't add up in my mind. Oh, and answers *couldn't exist* if there was no good question to answer. So, yeah... still not sure why questions aren't considered as important as answers.

Comment: @mason Oh, and I know it must have been you that downvoted my question just now because it was downvoted right before you left you comment here. *So why not leave a comment there for everyone to learn from?* This is what I'm getting on about. How do the old folks want the platform to improve if they aren't willing to properly teach the new people and actually help them ask good questions? I rarely see anyone actually helping out, I mostly just see people downvoting without explaining why (like you just did) which just demoralizes new users and drives them away.

Comment: @RtHarston of course I downvoted. It’s not on topic. I also voted to close it. I explained that to you already in my comment here. And I linked to the documentation that clearly states why it is off topic. I never said you can’t ask questions - I clearly stated what we are looking for in a question.

Comment: @mason And the link you sent me says to me it is on topic, so who is interpreting it correctly? And my point about where you left your comment isn't about me, it is about other people who come across a down-voted question with no explanation of why it was downvoted, so they have no idea what is wrong with it and what they should or should not do to have their questions downvoted as well, and so their questions will maybe be better too, helping with what you yourself are complaining about in your other comments.

Comment: @RTHarston I am right about what is on topic in this case. The relevant bit: `Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above.....Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.` Your question clearly violates that. As for not leaving a comment, I explained to you here what was wrong with it, and I was confident the question would get closed and leave an adequate explanation. Plus, I think it's obvious.

Answer (score 102):

No, there was no such discussion raised by the SE team to normal community members.

There was a consultation made to moderators *only* in the private moderator [Team](https://stackoverflow.com/teams). This was leaked to the public here in a now-deleted and redacted question. (Someone managed to archive it to WayBackMachine before it was removed, but SE contacted them and asked them to remove it. <s>If you want to see a copy of that post, I'm afraid you'll just have to look for it elsewhere.</s> After this change was put in place, the archived page was reinstated.)

This spawned a [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337757/should-the-weight-of-question-upvotes-be-increased-back-up-to-10) here, but that was erased by a local moderator here (not an employee) as apparently it was attracting too much drama. (There was another post asking if the earlier post was real, which was also removed by a local mod.)

Comment: I think the wayback page was restored- at least it’s working for me again.

Comment: @CobyViner You aren’t really missing anything.  It was leaked to stir up drama and doesn’t have any useful information that isn’t already released. The leak itself is worth mentioning, but the content of the leak is pretty meh. It’s just more of people getting upset because we have little ability  to influence what happens.

Comment: @CobyViner Website owners are allowed to have archived pages removed upon request by contacting them. (It also used to be possible to have pages removed by using robots.txt, but they later discontinued this practice.)

Comment: Suggested edit: moderators were not consulted re the policy itself. They were informed about the policy. They were consulted about how best to pitch it to the community.

Comment: @ColleenV, but the leaked Teams post (the quote from the deleted Meta post) showed quite a bit of detail about the number of users that were granted which additional privileges, and referred to some studies that are not mentioned in the blog or elsewhere now?

Comment: @Arjan that's correct.

Comment: I don't think the Meta post that leaked the Teams content has been wiped from archive.org, but @Coby's URL above refers to a different post. (I don't know if _that_ post was ever captured.)

Comment: @Arjan It was wiped, but later reinstated.

Comment: @Arjan Those numbers were mostly from SEDE queries and are out-dated. I think some of them were found to be miscalculated for some reason. I’m certain we could find or ask for better numbers in a constructive way without dredging up old drafts that were never intended to be released to the public.

Comment: @ColleenV, thank, that might clarify the lack of numbers. Still weird that the _"independent research"_ is not mentioned at all, but well.

Comment: @Arjan That’s one thing they listened to feedback on; I don’t think it would be nice to stir up trouble over it.

Comment: Frankly, the independant research was... garbage.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Doesn't matter - it had all the right keywords in it

Comment: Demanding the Wayback Machine censors things like this is abhorrent. Yes, trust was breached by the leaker. Yes, it's embarrassing for the staff (their fault for coming up with it in the first place though). No, it does not contain "sensitive personal information". Get a grip, SE.

Answer (score 54):

There was [Should the weight of question upvotes be increased network-wide?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337843/134729), asked on November 9, 2019, although it was asked by a community member, not by the SE team.

Comment: And the answer was a pretty overwhelming "no."

Comment: Note that the asker was Robert Harvey, who was a moderator on Stack Overflow prior to his [resignation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389906/425313) - so slightly more notable than a post by a random community member. He likely had some privileged knowledge that the change was under consideration.

Comment: @BradKoch This wasn't announced to mods until after he resigned.. but it was leaked.. which directly led to several questions being posted here, and then removed (see the comments on that question) - until that one was asked without any direct reference to the leak, which I guess it why it wasn't removed.

Answer (score 46):

Another addendum to the answer by [JC007B](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338151/285661), the Director of Product Marketing at SE Inc.:

> We didn't solicit feedback from the wider community on this change. We have a robust roadmap and we are selective in asking the community for feedback on specific releases.

In other words:

- SE Inc., on its own, solely, decides what goes on its product road map.
- Of course, the road map isn't disclosed. (btw: "Thanks", that answers my [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337923/can-progress-data-for-feature-requests-be-made-publicly-available-to-the-communi) where I suggested it would be great for communication to share some of that information with us.)
- SE Inc. also, solely, decides when to ask about feedback, and when to not do that.

So, basically, the new corporate communication philosophy can be summarized with:

*Take it or leave it.*

Makes total sense.

It is really not like the community and the users are in any way stakeholders in a sense of Agile development. And only stakeholders get a voice that needs to be listened to.

Comment: "Inclusivity" means "we don't really include anybody as stakeholders, we just pretend".

Comment: Yeah, well, me, I'm leaving it. No more questions, no more answers, no more reviews. I feel cheated. I thought I was helping people, somewhere, but I was just helping to enhance shareholder value. This action is yet another step down into mediocrity. Shame.

Comment: @RedSonja I still feel ambiguous. I am not a "first day" member, so I never attached myself to "the company" like others did. I always figured that I was contributing to the commercial success of a company, and that they *own* the servers, thus my work. And just to say something positive: the technical folks at SE Inc. are great people to work with. I disagree with the way the "question-change" was pushed on us, but I very much appreciate how flawless that worked out. That part of *really working* with some folks at SE Inc. that still works...

Answer (score 22):

Some addition to [JC007B answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338151/260198). It wasn't feedback about the theme itself. Moderators were only asked about the pitching part.

Answer (score -32):

We informed site moderators of the change a few weeks ago, collected their input, and responded to it. We trust our moderators as representatives of their communities.

We didn't solicit feedback from the wider community on this change. We have a robust roadmap and we are selective in asking the community for feedback on specific releases.

As for why we didn't solicit feedback on this, Sara said it best in the blog post, "This change is about more than reputation; we want it to send a clear message—we celebrate the question askers."

Comment: I could understand coming up with the idea and workshopping it among staff and moderators first, but with all the recent controversy, you had to anticipate that the community would prefer to provide input as well. And failure to do so -- whether the right approach or not -- would simply turn the community even more against the staff.

Comment: Did you solicit feedback on the actual policy, or just how to pitch it.

Comment: @AndyG: With all the recent controversy I thought it's pretty obvious they don't *want* community feedback... :|

Comment: At least we are finally hearing the voice of the Director of Product Marketing.

Comment: To be clear, it does not appear that you did solicit feedback **on the policy**, but rather only on how to pitch it. If you would like to repair the relationship and start building trust with the community, you should *be completely honest*.

Comment: I'm a site moderator and didn't know about this. Maybe I missed something. When did you inform me?

Comment: I can tell you what we did do. We sought feedback on open questions that we felt the network's moderators would be best equipped to help us answer / be prepared for together (e.g., impact on privileges, etc.). They know their communities best and we trust them to help us see blindspots in these areas. Their feedback did influence how it was communicated.

Comment: @MeganRisdal So you were planning on not actually gathering feedback to change how this was implemented at all, but only getting feedback from a few moderators about how to *market* this? So you're turning moderators into marketing analysts? Why was the community itself not asked? Why couldn't you just create a meta post, make your case? And then incorporate the feedback received - even if it turns out that making this change is overwhelmingly not what the community wants?

Comment: @MeganRisdal Did you seek this feedback after or before a large number of moderators resigned or became inactive?

Comment: The blog post also says (in its last paragraph) "These changes ... are an exciting start to working hand in hand with the community to build a better Stack Overflow." I'm uncertain about how that squares with "We didn't solicit feedback from the wider community on this change."

Comment: @DoubleAA The announcement and updates were posted on the mod team and also discussed/starred/etc in TL.

Comment: Communities do not elect their moderators to  make them unilateral decision-making representatives. Representation outside the network implies that the moderators  show the world the why and the best of the community, because otherwise we would  be giving sort of political power to them. If a decision affects the whole of the community than it is not morally right to  consider moderators' views as the will of the community. I'm a Moderator and I disgree with this post (as conveyed rather indirectly) that my or of my fellow moderator's views alone count as the decision  of the community.

Comment: @EmC so the OP meant "We informed some site moderators who frequent the dedicated moderator Team and Chatroom of the changes..." If they really wanted to inform the site mods they could have used a push mod notification or dropped a notice to check out the Team in the per site mod chat rooms.

Comment: "collected their input, and responded to it" Would you say they were generally supportive of this change?

Comment: @EmC (sometimes they push notification or ping us in site chat rooms.) I'm not angry for not finding out, that is indeed my fault, but I'm unhappy this post gives the impression I was consulted. The people who frequent TL and the Team are a non-random subset of moderators.

Comment: This new ["Staff" mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/430118/jc007b) is a good thing.

Comment: @DeNovosupportsGoFundMonica they have asked us only about pitching part.

Comment: @Megan, _"Their [moderators] feedback did influence how it was communicated"_: the leaked first draft emphasised on who would benefit from the change, which after the said feedback is now nowhere to be found. That really makes me wonder if/feel that you (SE inc) searched for a reason _after_ coming up with the changes. And that in times where trust is that low. :-(

Comment: You pursue this strategy at your peril. The consent of the governed (the community) to governance is essentially for its efficacy. If you think that you can fight the community head on and win, SE may soon join the large cadre of companies that held such hubris and failed all the same. I'm sorry, but this whole attitude belies a catastrophic failure in management and vision.

Comment: It seems that this is the only answer that answers all the questions asked in the original post, based in fact, without speculation or fierce opinions on related subjects. On any other SE site that would mean that this would be the accepted answer. What is going on here that instead it gets all these downvotes? Does the Q&A format work different here on meta than on the main sites? This is an honest question, not a rhetorical one. Can somebody please explain?

Comment: It's nice to see you. I appreciate that we're seeing "new" faces on Meta, even if you've been an employee for awhile. Despite my tumultuous feelings on everything going on, I can still acknowledge that posts like this are a change. So, please know that it's *noticed*, and please continue.

Comment: We've had some well known recent examples of the fact that "Sara says" now seems to be sufficient justification for anything. I read the subtext as "any fool can ask questions, and the more fools we attract to SE, the higher  the advertising click-through rate will be". Sure, fools might ask poor questions, but who cares about that if they feel "rewarded" enough to click on the ads?

Comment: A suggestion? Perhaps make some of the roadmap public? I know you said previously something like 'default always transparent is not always feasible', but a public roadmap for a company is _very_ common. And of course it doesn't need to be hyper detailed, just the big ticket items. I think that would go a _LOOOOONNGGG_ way towards the transparency and trust rebuilding that we keep getting promised.

Comment: I am the typical user who you'd think would benefit from this change. When I joined the community, I did not feel I'd fit it, was scared to ask questions, and felt most of the things described in [Sara's post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/). I just want to say that I still oppose this. I feel that I have earned my place here, and now DO fit in; I don't need extra points. This change is just in line with the "include everyone"-trend. You should at least have cared more about the opinions of your users (that's the whole point of SE right, voting).

Comment: @Vincent While I do agree in principle, and do not encourage downvoting this, I still understand how things like this does not always work exactly like intended; especially since I think this is somewhat of a rare situation: Users feeling they have no other way of expressing their opinion towards the staff. The comments rarely does work like intended e.g.; If they did, we wouldn't be having this conversation here, and you would not have asked such a question in the comments in the first place either.

Comment: @Vincent : But, I guess I also should've taken your last point more literally (apologies), so to answer your question: No, the voting of course works like everywhere else, as indicated by the note when you place the pointer over the vote button.